# Call multiple subvariables from only on pillar.sls file through top.sls

Tags: salt-stack

I have some issues trying to call some targeted pillars in my top.sls from only one pillar file.

Everything works if my call targets one file with one pillar in it, but I have more than 20 files and I would like to compile everything in one file (easier to maintain).

**Actual situation:**

`Top.sls`

```yaml
base:
  '*':
  - folder.site.test1
  - folder.site.test2
etc...
```

`test1.sls`

```yaml
global:
  test1: |
    blabla
```

`test2.sls`

```yaml
global:
  test2: |
    bloblo
```

Salt output:

```
> sudo salt "*-1" pillar.get global
X-1:
-------
  test1:
    blabla
  test2:
    bloblo

> sudo salt "*-1" pillar.get global:test1 
X-1:
  blabla
```

**What I tried:**

I would like have only one file and  be able to target one "subpillar" and call it when needed.

I tried a lot of things before asking for help, nothing worked for me, I think I'm missing some specifics notions on this.

`Top.sls`

```yaml
base:
  '*':
    - folder.site.pillar.test1
```

`pillar.sls`

```yaml
global:
  test1: |
    blabla
  test2: |
    bloblo
```

Salt output:

```
> sudo salt "*-1" saltutil.refresh_pillar

[ERROR   ] Specified SLS 'folder.site.pillar.test1' in environment 'base' is not available on the salt master

[CRITICAL] Pillar render error: Specified SLS 'folder.site.pillar.test1' in environment 'base' is not available on the salt master
```

Comment: `top.sls` is supposed to list the files. It's not clear what you're trying to do or why you would expect that to work.

Comment: Additionally, if you have non-secret data targeted to all minions, there's not much point it being in a pillar in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Actually, i try to dispatch a list of element in server's pillars through a lot of pre-requisite (name/state/roles)(which is working), but i need to preserve some data's server from others, and in order to have one file and not 20/30 to maintain, that's why i try to do this!